# Is it possible to submit an array of objects?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3, and I'm having trouble submitting arrays of objects to my controller. Is it possible? And if not, is there a workaround so that I can submit multiple objects at once?

Example request:

```
let req = {
    'data[]': [
        { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'test2' }
    ]
};
```

Then, to test, I simply returned the contents of the request:

```
public function testArray(Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

And got this result:

```
data: [
    "[object Object]",
    "[object Object]"
]
```

Comment: How are you sending the data in the request? I mean.. how do you construct your payload?

Comment: @HCK I'm sending it via jquery with the exact same object I put on the question. Arrays of primitives go through just fine, but arrays of objects fail

Comment: Are you using the header `Content-type: application/json`?

Comment: No, but where would I add the header? In the request or the response?

Comment: In the request. This headers tells Laravel that the incoming data is in that format (`json`). Additionally, you can also add another one telling the format that you expect: `Accept: application/json`

Comment: Just tried it, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your js

```
let req = [
    { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'test2' }
];

var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: baseurl + "/test-data",
    type: 'post',
    data:{
        req:req
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

In controller:

```
public function testArray(Request $request) {
     $post = $request->all();

     return response()->json($post);
}
```

In route file: (web.php)

Here I used DemoController you can replace with your controller name

```
Route::post('/test-data', 'DemoController@testArray');
```

Result:

```
req: (2) […]
​​
0: Object { id: "1", name: "test1" }
​​
1: Object { id: "2", name: "test2" }
​​
length: 2
```

Comment: I simulated your request with ajax, like this:

`$.post({
 url: 'my url',
 headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'my token'
 },
 data: [
  { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'test2' }
 ]
})
.always(res => console.log(res));`

The php code was the same as you put in your answer, and my response was an empty array.

Comment: Tried it, got empty array as response

Comment: Please copy paste my code as it is. Just change your controller name only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193774/discussion-between-natvarsinh-parmar-bapu-and-ayrton).

Comment: My mistake was adding the `Content-type` header like the first answer told me, without it your code works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, result is an array of objects, result[0] is the first object. To access the id for example, you would use result[0]['id']. 
You can use a for loop for example to see real data.

Also I think u can use json_encode.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nope, I checked it on console and my result is literally an array of strings "[object Object]". Using `json_encode` on the controller also didn't help, because my `data` array contained only strings "[object Object]" there too.

Comment: u cant check that in console... use dd($results) in your backend function

Comment: Yes I can, using `console.log` on an object will show its whole structure. And an answer below told me to use `dd($results)` in the controller and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

`return` is often having issues when displaying objects/arrays.
Try simply:

```
dd($request->all())
```

instead of `return`, you'll be surprised :)

Comment: Got an empty array as response